# NullPointerEx at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext line 1401

Tags: java, hibernate

I have asked this question in Hibernate forum for a week without an anwser - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1011634. I am really stuck here and hopefully can get help here. I got NullPointerException from org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.

My hibernate dependency is as follows:

org.hibernate
hibernate-entitymanager
3.5.6-Final

The exception stack is below:

```
        2011-07-04 07:06:38,691 DEBUG [http-8080-2] mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.HttpInvokerServiceExporter (HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:168) - java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.replaceDelayedEntityIdentityInsertKeys(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1401)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.postInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:117)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:89)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:267)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:259)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeInserts(ActionQueue.java:169)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:204)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:130)
at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(EJB3PersistEventListener.java:69)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:179)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:774)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:778)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:668)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
at $Proxy138.persist(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
at $Proxy59.persist(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate$5.doInJpa(JpaTemplate.java:264)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.execute(JpaTemplate.java:183)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate.persist(JpaTemplate.java:262)
at mobi.esca.persistence.GenericJPARepository.persist(GenericJPARepository.java:153)
at mobi.esca.persistence.GenericJPARepository.persistAll(GenericJPARepository.java:161)
at mobi.esca.mars.application.UsageManager.logUsageStats(UsageManager.java:43)
at mobi.esca.mars.interfaces.mobile.EndUserController.reportStats(EndUserController.java:259)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
at $Proxy137.reportStats(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.RemoteInvocationAdaptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationAdaptor.java:89)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.RemoteInvocationAdaptor.proceed(RemoteInvocationAdaptor.java:54)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:59)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.MethodInvocationRateFromUserProtection.doFilter(MethodInvocationRateFromUserProtection.java:56)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:56)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.MethodInvocationRateFromIpProtection.doFilter(MethodInvocationRateFromIpProtection.java:57)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:56)
at mobi.esca.mars.interfaces.mobile.ClientVersionChecker.doFilter(ClientVersionChecker.java:41)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:56)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:37)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:56)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:201)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequestInternal(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:128)
at mobi.esca.mobile.remoting.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
```

I am looking at the line 1401 of StatefulPersistenceContext.java file:

```
1396   public void replaceDelayedEntityIdentityInsertKeys(EntityKey oldKey, Serializable generatedId) {
1397      Object entity = entitiesByKey.remove( oldKey );
1398      EntityEntry oldEntry = ( EntityEntry ) entityEntries.remove( entity );
1399      parentsByChild.clear();
1400
1401      EntityKey newKey = new EntityKey( generatedId, oldEntry.getPersister(), getSession().getEntityMode() );
1402      addEntity( newKey, entity );
```

so the possible null object here could be oldEntry, right? Could anyone tell me when oldEntry can become null? What can i do to fix the problem?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Cheng Wei

---

Hi Moe,

Thanks for your reply. The exception are happening randomly in various methods in our system now, and i can not recreate it by unit test. I will give a simplest code from a method.

```
@Controller
public class EndUserController implements EndUserService, InvocationContextRequired
{
    @Override
    public void reportStats(UsageStatsDTO usageStatsDTO) throws ClientVersionOutOfDateException
    {
        log.debug("enter UsageReportController.reportStats()");
        UsageStats usageStats = usageStatsDTO.asUsageStats(getEndUser());
        usageManager.logUsageStats(usageStats);
        if(usageStats.hasAppStartEvent())
        {
            endUserManager.updateClientVersion(getEndUser(), getClientVersion());
        }
        log.debug("exit UsageReportController.reportStats()");
    }
    ......
}

@Service
public class UsageManager
{
    @Autowired
    private CallEventRepository callEventRepository;
    @Autowired
    private AppStartEventRepository appStartEventRepository;
    @Autowired
    private InviteEventRepository inviteEventRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void logUsageStats(UsageStats usageStats)
    {
        if (usageStats.hasCallEvent())
        {
            callEventRepository.persistAll(usageStats.getCallEvents());
        }
        if (usageStats.hasAppStartEvent())
        {
            appStartEventRepository.persistAll(usageStats.getAppStartEvents());
        }
        if (usageStats.hasInviteEvent())
        {
            inviteEventRepository.persistAll(usageStats.getInviteEvents());
        }
    }
    ......
}

public class GenericJPARepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
    implements GenericRepository<T, ID>
{
    @Override
    public T persist(T entity)
    {
        getJpaTemplate().persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }
    @Override
    public void persistAll(Collection<T> entities)
    {
        for(T entity : entities)
        {
            persist(entity);
        }
    }
    ......
}
```

And all RepositoryImpl classes are the subclasses(CallEventRepository,AppStartEventRepository,InviteEventRepository) of GenericJPARepository.

Many thanks,
Cheng Wei

---

Can problem be caused by i detach an entity? endUserRepository.detach(detatchedEndUser); But UsageStats, the object to be persisted, does not reference to detatchedEndUser.

---

Thanks Moe and Maurice, Appreciate your help. I finally find the problem. the following code caused the problem:

```
EndUser toBePersistedEndUser = endUserRepository.persist(new EndUser(remoteEndUser));
endUserRepository.detach(toBePersistedEndUser );
return toBePersistedEndUser;
```

Also, i think i reveal a bug for hibernate here.

Problem solved, Many thanks,
Cheng Wei

Answer (score 0):

Well, either oldEntry is null, or getSession() returns null.
Obviously, oldEntry will be null if the entityEntries doesn't contain the entry removed from entitiesByKey. It could also happen if the equals() method for EntityEntry is incorrectly implemented.